# Ruby IO.read on Windows

Tags: ruby, io

I am trying to write a program to read and write to files in Ruby and neither IO.read or IO.write work. I have read online that IO.read causes problems in Windows but I have not gotten a good answer on how to get it to work.

EDIT: The code I am using is up here

http://electrithm.net/random.rb

Comment: show your code and the error you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why, turns out I should have been using IO.binread thanks to all of you who read my question and didnt answer it and shouldn't be getting a shoutout at all.